# TinyMCE NetAdvImage virtual path

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, tinymce

I am trying to have a virtual directory outside of the my web where I upload files via TinyMCE for company marketing data, etc... For images, I'm using the netadvimage image uploader.

To set this up, I removed the physical directory /content/images/upload and created a virtual directory "uploaded" under /content/images/ in IIS7.

When the image uploader/selector comes up, it appends the physical path to the file name.  The window will come up with broken links and have something like this for the image. src="https://dev.mysite.comC:/MyUploaded/myimages/1-200X200.jpeg" 
C:/MyUploaded is where my virtual directory exists.  Since that is the case, it puts that instead of /content/images/uploaded (the virtual directory path)
Is there a way to tell it to  use the virtual path instead of the physical path?

The site is hosted in IIS 7 and is using Microsoft MVC3/c#.

Thanks in advance.   This has me stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that plugin uses valums ajax uploader. You need to specify your path like so:

endpoint: '/upload/endpoint' OR try: '../../upload/endpoint'